# How to align mouse pointer quickly in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

For example:

```
def imshow(img):
    img = img/2+0.5
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1,2,0)))
    plt.show()
```

after type in this function, the screen focus is just at the ')' position. Now I need to move the focus to the next line, but aligns with 'def', not 'plt', is there a way to do that? Currently after I type in my function and press 'enter', it automatically alines with 'plt', not 'def'.

Comment: did you try tab and shift+tab ? or backspace?

Comment: Yes, shit+tab seems working. Just that not that convenient.